# How to find out what modules are adding links to a menu?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I was wondering if there's any way to find out what modules are adding links to what menus using hook_menu()? I don't care if it's a module or custom code added to Drupal core, I just need to know. There's a link showing up in my main menu and I have no idea what's putting it there. I'd really rather not go through every single module and check their menu hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a particular menu entry, search the `menu_router` table for the path or something that matches the path if arguments are used, and then use a [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to print the menu item to debug:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter (&$items)
{
  print_r($items["foo/bar/baz"]);
}
```

Then look at the `page callback` index.  If will contain a string with the function name that gets called for that menu item (see [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more details).  In general, the callback function will closely match the module name.  For example, if the callback is "foo_bar_generate_a_page" then the "foo" or "foo_bar" module owns that menu entry.

Answer (score 3):

You're after [module_implements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_implements/7). It will allow you to specify the hook (in this case 'menu') and then get an array of module names back.
Of course, you'll still need to manually open the files to check, but you should be able to narrow it down from the menu path and title.

It might be worth flushing the caches too.

Comment: The main problem with module_implements for chasing down a menu router entry is that just about every module (or at least a large majority) implements hook_menu for settings pages.  You end up having to examine just about every module anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Most text editors (notepad++, sublime text, textmate, etc) have "Find in files" functionality that you can use to search your entire Drupal codebase. Just put in the path you're curious about (e.g., `user/login` or `admin/appearance`) and point it to your `sites/all/modules` folder and it should point out exactly what module's `hook_menu` is responsible.

If it doesn't find anything, make sure you're not searching for a menu that has arguments. If I wanted to know what module is responsible for `node/add/page` I would need to make sure to leave off `/page` since that won't be hardcoded in any `hook_menu`.